# Shadow Catcher not transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, shadowcatcher

Maybe I do something wrong, but I read multiple posts about it and looked into different videos. I should do it right but it's just not working.

I want to have a plane that just catches the shadow of my basketball. I enabled `Shadow Catcher` in the `Visibility` tab of the plane, but the plane is still visible.

Is something set up wrong in my scene? Or is it bugged somehow?

I'm using blender on windows if this is relevant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of blender are u using? Shadow catcher doesn't work with cycles-x

Comment: as below, check that under Render Properties > Film,  Transparent check is checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works, in 3.0.0 alpha too.

Here is the result:

[image]

I made the cube smaller so you don't see too much shadow of the cube on the plane, because else you think you see the plane and not the shadow of the cube on the plane.

Go to render properties -> Film -> Check transparent

[image]

UPDATE:
additional answer to your question in comment:

to remove the shadow from the plane which is there because of the cube, select the cube and uncheck: shadow in ray visibility

[image]

then you get:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I feel dumb now. It's not the actual plane that I see, it's the big shadow of my cube...

Comment: Don’t feel dumb. We all started some time ago with Blender and learnt. That’s normal. Learning is a process ;)

Comment: Thanks. One more quick question (maybe I should open another one for this). How can I remove the shadow of the cube on the ground and only display it on the ball? In my original file there is an image plane in front which already got the shadows on the ground. I just need those shadows on the basketball.

Comment: i updated my answer...just scroll down. It is the "shadow" checkbox, which you have to uncheck for the cube

Answer (score 2):

Your shadow catcher is working as expected, you just need to turn on Transparency under Render properties > Film > Transparent.

If you don't want or need Transparency and you want the background color to render, you need to make the plane bigger, because right now, your plane is as big as your shadows, the shadows reach the border of the plane and you see the shape of the plane because of that

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That also solved my problem. But Chris was faster :-)